# Update Dataframe while iterating through it - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my first time working with `DataFrame` and I am badly stuck on a point where I need to Update `DataFrame`.

My dataframe object has some basic values like `userId, userName, address` and then I need to call a model that returns a list of values (Currently 36 values). I need to append that values in existing dataframe object. **Either in single cell or in multiple cells in same row.**

> But I'm getting different errors while trying different methods.

This is my current Dataframe:

```
UserId UserName Address 
1      User1    Add1
2      User2    Add2
```

This is what I want to do:

```
UserId UserName Address Res
1      User1    Add1    [1,2,3...36]
2      User2    Add2    [1,2,3...36]
```

Or something like this:

```
UserId UserName Address Res1 Res2 Res3... Res36
1      User1    Add1    1      2    3 ... 36
2      User2    Add2    1      2    3 ... 36
```

Currently I'm using this method..

```
for index, row in rawData.iterrows():
    res = calculateData(row)
    rawData['res'] = pd.Series(res, index=rawData.index)
```

It throws this error:

> ValueError: Length of passed values is 36, index implies 96.

On debugging, I got to know that, it is trying to add all values (36) for each row (96) in my dataframe while I'm trying to add it in a cell of index. I did try some different methods as well but All I got is length error because every method adds list to each row..

> Any help on how can I achieve my required result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension on dataframe index and call function `calculateData` inside list comprehension.

Assume your function `calculateData` is defined as follows:

```
def calculateData(x):
    return np.arange(36) + x.name


rawData['res'] = [calculateData(rawData.loc[i]) for i in rawData.index]

Out[20]:
   UserId UserName Address                                                res
0       1    User1    Add1  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...
1       2    User2    Add2  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14...
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.. Thank you

Comment: @NullPointer: you are welcome. Glad I could help :)